# Unity - referencing another game object Text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Working on my first game, and I am trying to create a game manager script which I attached to an object I called `GameManager`.

In the `GameManager` script I have a public reference to a UI Text. But when when refencing this text within a static function of the GameManager I get `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. 
I did drag it into its place in the inspector.

The reason this function is static it's because it needs to be called whenever one of the tiles in the game is being clicked.

I am assuming that the reference to this text is for some reason not the instance. But I don't understand how am I supposed to instantiate it when it's already in my scene.

Thought to create a private method that is being called when the public static one is called but not sure if it's a good practice.

Would really appreciate some clarification on how to get the instance and what went wrong.

Thank you very much in advance

**EDIT: Adding `GameManager.cs`**
I got the error for the first line of `AddScore()`

```
public static Text score; //declared at the top

... // some irrelevant logic

public static void AddScore()
    {
        int currentScore = int.Parse(score.text);
        currentScore += scoreToAdd;
        score.text = currentScore.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: seems like you are trying to access a non-static variable from a static method, this is not possible (as far as I know). Could you post your code, to check if there is a workaround to what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Lotan Thank you, I added the relevant parts of the code

Comment: Is it possible to assign static fields in the inspector? :O I thought it wouldn't be possible. The workaround, I thought, would be to assign it in the Start() method.

Comment: @FredrikSchön Thanks, my bad, it was indeed unassigned. It started as non static . So in `Start()` I should find it with `GetComponent<Text>()`? Would that be correct?

Comment: I should think so, yes! Given that the Text component is on the GameManager component. Probably do an `if (score == null ) score = GetComponent<Text>();` since it's a singleton and should only be assigned once. However, I'd say you probably want the entire GameManager to be a static class. Do you _need_ it to be a MonoBehaviour (=attached to a gameobject & gets the Start(), Update() callback, etc)? Probably not! Do some reading on google for unity singletons, is my suggestion!

Comment: Thanks again @FredrikSchön for the detailed explanation! Will look up your suggestions